# Probability of drawing the minimum within a group

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose there are *n* individuals each drawing a value from some distribution G(.). What is the probability of a given individual drawing the lowest value among the *n* people?

Note: I am not asking about the probability of drawing the minimum of G(.); rather, I am asking about the probability of drawing the minimum of the set of *n* values drawn by the group of *n* people.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no ties, it's $1/n$ - each of them is equally likely to draw the lowest.

Comment: You might add that if the probability of a tie is nonzero, then it's impossible to answer the question without knowing more about the distribution.